# double grouping

Tags: sql-server

```
someid    somestring   SomeValue
  1        Hello          value1
  1        Hello          value2
  1        Blah           value3
  2        World          value4
  2        TestA          value5
  2        TestB          value6
  1        Hello          value7       
  1        World          value8
  1        Blah           value9 
  2        TestB          value10
  2        TestB          value11 
  2        TestB          value12
```

I need the result set to be like this

```
someid    somestring    Count(SomeValue)
  1        Hello          3
  1        Blah           2
  2        World          2
  2        TestA          1
  2        TestB          4
```

Can some one plase help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
select someid,something,count(*)
from table
group by someid,something
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    someid,
    somestring,
    count(*) 
from 
    myTable 
group by 
    someid,
    somestring
```